# Are there sources in Prague that have hand-held, printed maps?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, maps, walking, prague

For my bucket-list trip to Prague/Praha and with an architectural history background, I want to make the most of my time in this City of a Thousand Spires.

I prefer to wander throughout a city, get its sense of place, feel its soul and its history. My navigational gene wants to orient me, and let me understand through the use of with maps and street guides.

And I would like to do it without digital assistance, as it narrows my focus to an app on a mobile device. While I do plan to use an app, I'd like to have printed versions of good walking and transportation maps, and am especially interested in what might be obtainable locally.

Are there for sources in Prague that have hand-held, printed maps? If available, it would be useful to have sources for printed guides/maps of transit options, both under and above ground and those that indicate taxi stands. It would be handy, although not a requisite, to find maps that can be mounted on a bicycle/scooter to navigate as you go.

And, as a side note, on return home, the printed map is very useful in identifying the thousands of images taken.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Are there for sources in Prague that have hand-held, printed maps?

Maps are easy to obtain in Prague, no matter how you come to the country.

**Airport**: A free map is available at the airport's public transport information kiosks.

[image]

**Train station**: The main train station likewise gives out free maps at the public transport information counters.

[image]

**City center**: The city's official Visitor Center gives out free maps on **Rytirska 12** (Staromestske Namesti).

[image]

**Book stores**: any large bookstore (e.g. **Neoluxor** on Vaclavske Namesti) sells maps of various resolutions. You can usually get maps for both Prague and the entire Czech Republic, as well as various surrounding countries.

> If available, it would be useful to have sources for printed guides/maps of transit options, both under and above ground

Every map I've seen has the public transport options displayed, although some lack the bus stops.

> and those that indicate taxi stands

While some maps may display those, I advise you against ever taking a taxi from an official taxi stand, as that's where most tourists get ripped off. There's even a notorious [Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eccBS7mDd2o) where a guy pretends to be a tourist and takes numerous official taxis.

> to find maps that can be mounted on a bicycle/scooter to navigate as you go.

I haven't seen those on sale, but perhaps try your luck at the bike rentals.

Comment: Good advice. I can attest to being scammed by a taxi from a taxi stand earlier this year on my second day.

Comment: Btw, every metro station and most tram and bus stops have large and very detailed maps of the city showing all the public transportation lines. They also show time-related information on tram lines (such as lines operating on peak hours only) but not bus lines.

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty available. The airport tourist information counter has a high number of excellent maps of Prague and the public transport system. Hotels also usually have several maps available, covering the Old Prague and the Prague Castle area.

The public transportation map comes in two versions, one which is folds out of a pamphlet explaining all the costs and procedure to use various modes of transportation, all in several languages. The other one is a fold out map which is easier that shows the network of trams, metros and buses.

Maps provided by hotels include labels for most places of interest to tourists, including historical sites, places of worship, museums, etc.